# Change multiple CSS classes with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to change 5 classes that have the same name with another name using JS

```js
var left = document.getElementById("right").className = "left";
```

```css
.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeLeft()">Sinistra</button>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="images/angular.png" alt="HTML" id="right" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: 5 classes that have the same name ? explain

Comment: All the classes are named "right" and I want that with a button all of the 5 classes that have that name will be renamed in "left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use simple jQuery for this :

```js
function changeLeft() {
  $('.right').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('right');
    $(this).addClass('left');
  });
}
```

```css
.newsright {
clear:both;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeLeft()">Sinistra</button>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/50/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/60/40/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

you may also make the button to switch between both classes like this :

```js
function switchClass() {
  $('.right,.left').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('right left');
  });
}
```

```css
.newsright {
clear:both;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="switchClass()">Sinistra</button>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/50/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/60/40/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div class="newsright">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="HTML" class="right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `$(this).toggleClass('right');` and `$(this).toggleClass('left');` you can simply write `$(this).toggleClass('right left');`.

Comment: @AhmadMaleki yes you are right, it's updated. I just made a copy paste of the first one without doing optimization :)

Answer (score -1):

Were you searching for this: [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jts9mgcu/).

```
<script>
   function changeLeft () {
      var left = document.getElementById("right").className = "left";
   }
</script>
```

Simply when clicking on the changeLeft function the elements with such a class are changed to right: